# What do you call a person with a good memory? Does 'intelligent' work?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Can a person with great memory power be called **intelligent**? Or is there any other word or phrase to describe such a person?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although I would have to agree with both snailboat and hjpotter92's choice of ***eidetic*** and ***mnemonist*** as words meaning "someone who is very good at remembering", it really isn't particularly idiomatic. Most native speakers would say:

> John has a photographic memory.

Rather than

> John is eidetic.

[image]

And

> Jill has a good memory

Rather than

> Jill is a mnemonist.

In general, as a native speaker I would prefer terms that are *widely understood* and *in common usage* rather than ones which are *concise*, so unless you have particularly good reason to expect the person you're talking to to know the term *eidetic*, I'd probably just stick with something similar to the following:

> Jane has amazing memory prowess.
>
> John's memory is fantastic.
>
> Bill has a surprisingly good memory.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Every once in a while, there _is_ a word that describes someone or something, but you're usually much better off eschewing that word and going with a more common phrase instead. Another good example is _philatelist_; I'd say that 95% of the time, we'd be better off using _stamp collector_ instead.

Comment: @J.R. agreed.  Outside of the phrase "Who needs a hobby like..." philately and all other words sharing the same root should be dumped into a memory hole.

Comment: @Dan: "philately" will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 5):

No. Intelligence is a term used for one or more of the following cases:

> 1. The ability to comprehend; to understand and profit from experience
> 2. Possessing sound knowledge
> 3. The capacity to reason

People with good memory, on the other hand, are referred to as **eidetic**. **Eidetic memory** or **photographic memory** would be the correct term.

Answer (score 2):

The word you want is **memorious**. It's most famously used in the title of Borges's short story Funes the Memorious, which is about a man who remembers everything. Literally.

Comment: I think I'd be using _memorious_ to refer to some **easy to remember** event. Somewhat similar to _memorable_.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Why wouldn't you use **memorable** instead?

Comment: I'm not sure it's "the word you want." Sure, it's an apt word, at least according to [this dictionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/memorious); but it's also a rather rare word, so much so that [many dictionaries don't even list it](http://www.onelook.com/?w=memorious&ls=a). I'd be inclined to call this _"a word you might consider,"_ as opposed to _"the word you want."_

Answer (score 1):

*Eidetic* memory is a specific phenomenon - an image which persists only for a few minutes - which is extremely rare in adults.

*Photographic* memory probably doesn't occur at all, as an ability to remember any image ever seen.

People whose memories are commonly referred to as 'eidetic' or 'photographic' do usually  just have good memories (and/or they're using specific memory techniques).

Full recall of every event that's ever happened to an individual (autobiographical memory) is 'hyperthymesia' or 'hyperthymestic syndrome' and has only been very recently confirmed to exist.

http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2006/04/kaavya_syndrome.single.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthymesia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jill_Price

"[The Woman Who Could Not Forget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoxsMMV538U)" (TV)

"[The Woman Who Can't Forget](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=be0hQI8RHZYC&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A1416561765&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)" (book)

I'd stick with "**X has a good memory**". :)